# Inline content within Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am converting a PSD file and now I have two cards, and I want the content within the card to be like [this](https://imgur.com/M6lYFwA?fbclid=IwAR1aYV7I8XoZhzgDxrfzYZdFBMUq0YDCZhQIHPX5mYqo-_OcuSrxbTK9W2M).
Anyone can help me with that?

Here is my current code:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card height-2">
                    <i class="material-icons">gavel</i>
                    <h5>Legislacion</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card height-2">
                    <i class="material-icons">today</i>
                    <h5>Calendar</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Dominik says, if you are using `bootstrap-4`, you can use bootstrap classes

```css
/* ONLY FOR SPACE PURPOSE */

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row m-0">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card height-2 d-flex flex-row align-items-center p-3" style="border-top:4px solid #515151;">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="color:#515151;">gavel  </i>
                    <h5 class="pl-5 m-0">Legislacion</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card height-2 d-flex flex-row align-items-center p-3"  style="border-top:4px solid #9b9b60;">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:#9b9b60;">today</i>
                    <h5 class="pl-5 m-0">Calendar</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap >= 4, you can use special `d-flex` `justify-content-*` `align-items-*` classes in `row`

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card height-2">
                    <i class="material-icons">gavel</i>
                    <h5>Legislacion</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card height-2">
                    <i class="material-icons">today</i>
                    <h5>Calendar</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything!

Comment: Did you ran it ? It's what you wanted in picture

Answer (score 0):

I hope u r expecting like this:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.card.height-2 h5{
padding-left:40px;
}
.card {
   display: flex; 
   padding: 20px;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card height-2" style="border-top:4px solid #515151;">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="color:#515151;">gavel  </i>
                    <h5>Legislacion</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card height-2"  style="border-top:4px solid #9b9b60;">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:#9b9b60;">today</i>
                    <h5>Calendar</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```